# Reverse engineering - compile with debug info

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, reverse-engineering, reversing

I am learning about reversing a program and I was wondering .. if I compile with debug info :

```
gcc -g ....
```

Does this help the reversing process some how? do I give extra information if I do that? I Couldn't find any information about the subject.

Comment: debug information does not provide that kind of information.  Perhaps reading about  _[dis-assemblers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Disassembler)_ will help.

Comment: What do you mean by reverse-engineering, what do you expect produced by it ? (for instance some UML modeler have a reverse populating the UML model from the **sources**). The debug infos produced by the option `-g` are typically used by a debugger to associate an address with a line in a function/operation, to know where the variables are in memory/stack etc, but this is not a reverse-engineering

Comment: All `-g` should affect is whether symbolic debugging information is generated at compile+link times. It shouldn't actually affect the *code* generation. That said, is your *real* question whether compiling with `-g` somehow makes *your* code easier for *someone else* to reverse-engineer?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, this is exactly what I'm asking..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps by adding line numbers, file names, macro definitions and such to the resulting binary. However, it does not include the full source of the program inside the program itself.

Here's an example of macro definitions being included in the resulting file:

```sh
username@localhost /path/to/source/code $ gcc test.c -Wall -Wextra -gdwarf-4 -g3
username@localhost /path/to/source/code $ grep __STDC_VERSION__ a.out 
Binary file a.out matches
```

Debugging information is more useful for decompiling when compiling with `-g3`, as shown in the above example.

So, the answer to your question is: It gives a little bit of extra information that may be useful in decompiling, but not enough to be able to decompile and recompile the program successfully. If possible, just give the source code to the person.

If you want to prevent decompiling your code, just run `strip` on it like this after building and debugging your program:

```
strip program-file
```

`-g` should not affect code generation, it just adds information only useful to a debugger to the resulting program file.

If you want to prohibit someone from disassembling or decompiling your software, just include that in your license.

Comment: the macros definition / usage disappear *before* the compilation during the preprocessing and cannot be part of the debug infos

Comment: The information is included in the binary. Just `grep` something compiled with `-g3` for `__STDC_VERSION__` and you'll see.

Comment: do `#define AZE 1

int main()
{
  return AZE;
}` (on at least 2 lines of course) and compile with `-g` and you will not see _AZE_ in the binary/executable, you can also compile with the option `-E` and check _AZE_ does not appears in the result of the preprocessing

Comment: @bruno Sorry, that specific debugging information only appears when compiling with `-g3`.

Comment: ok with `-g3` you have the definition of _AZE_ (I didn't know that, thank you for learning me that) but not where it is used in the source, so the interest is very limited (in fact I do not see what it can be ^^)

Comment: @bruno The line number is not included as a string, but as a native-endian integer. A debugger will be more useful when testing for that.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.. I meant, If I compile my program with -g, -g3 or w/e , does it somehow helps another to do reverse engineering on my program ?

Comment: @sagi Somewhat. If possible, just give them the source code.

Comment: I mean I want to prevent reversing on my code. Does compiling like this affect it somehow , or it just doesn’t matter?

Comment: @sagi You want to prevent decompiling your code? If so, just run `strip` on it after you build it.

Comment: You’re missing my point. I’m not asking how to do it, I’m asking if compiling like this compromise it somehow

Comment: No. In no way will anyone ever get a working program from decompiling software. Just write a license that prohibits decompilation and disassembly.